# How can I manually enqueue plugin scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to manually use the accordion tool from wpbakery.  Now before my question gets closed, my question is not about wpbakery.

My question is how to load the correct scripts so that the accordion will work without actually using an accordion function in the page edit screen.

If editing a page and I add my short code (which adds HTML similar to the output that would be made if I added an accordion option from the wp-bakery edit screen), then on the front end that page doesn't present the accordion function correctly.  however if i add an accordion from my edit screen, then both the accordion and my shortcode output accordions on the front and both work perfectly.

I think it is because wp-bakery has a function that says "if you are using our accordion option, enqueue our js".

I had verified this by checking that this script is loaded when I add an accordion properly:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/vc_accordion/vc-accordion.min.js?ver=6.7.0' id='vc_accordion_script-js'></script>
```

is loaded, but otherwise it's not.

So I tried adding this code to functions.php:

```
function enqueue_scripts_style_page_content_using_shortcode(){
        wp_enqueue_script('vc_accordion_script-js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_only_if_page_using_shortcode' );
```

as well as

```
function enqueue_scripts_style_page_content_using_shortcode(){
        wp_enqueue_script('vc_accordion_script-js', 'https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/vc_accordion/vc-accordion.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_only_if_page_using_shortcode' );
```

However, neither load the script.

So my question is how to make sure this script is loaded even if I don't actually use the accordion widget from the plugin?

Comment: The first one should work if wp-bakery has registered the script handle, and the second one ought to work anyway. Are you sure this code is getting run? It might be worth trying some other handles in case wp-bakery cleans up any vc-* handles afterwards, or maybe looking at the logic it uses to decide whether to conditionally load the script in the first place and hooking into that if you can. If you disable wp-bakery does that work?

Comment: And there are probably better ways to construct the path to the file in the plugin without hard-coding the complete URL too.

Comment: Is it your own shortcode, or something included with the bakery thing?

Comment: @rup.  the code SHOULD be running, but thats the strange part.

Comment: @howard-e: its my own shortcode.